# What are some simple JQuery buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, button

With a simple JQuery command, it will turn a regular button into something awesome.

Comment: I just want to point out that using JavaScript to change HTML after the DOM is loaded, makes a noticeable switch on the buttons each time you load the page.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the javascript is inserted at the bottom of the HTML and is not in a document.ready or equivalent, then the switch might well be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/). You can turn many form controls/elements into pretty, themed button controls like this:

```
$("#aLink").button();
$(":checkbox").button();
// more in the docs
```

Comment: you did not provide an awesomeness rating ! :p

Comment: @Gaby - awesomeness is subjective, but if I have to, then I'll rate it as 7.5/10 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "button, input:submit, a" ).button();
    });
</script>
```